# Hypersurface orientable if it admits a smooth normal vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ a codimension 1 smooth submanifold of the n-dimensional smooth manifold $Y$. Assume $Y$ is oriented. We want to show that $X$ is orientable if and only if it admits a global smooth normal vector field (in Y).

How can we prove this? I have no idea how to even begin...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "normal vector field"?  Are you assuming that $Y$ has a Riemannian metric?  Or do you just mean that the vector field is transverse to $X$?

Comment: Yes, I meant $X$, sorry for that.

Comment: Um, I guess so, although I don't know too much about Riemannian metrics. Basically I'm thinking of $Y$ being embedded in some Euclidean space.

Comment: The concept of "normal" only makes sense when a Riemannian metric is present; the one from euclidean space should work.  The concept of "transverse" always makes sense.  Anyway, where are you getting this problem from?

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack problem 18 p. 106

Comment: What's your definition of "oriented"?

Comment: That you can smoothly orient the tangent space at each point; i.e. for each point there is a local parametrization around it such that its differential at each point preserves orientation.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  For $p\in X$, let $U_p$, with coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n,t)$, be a slice chart around $p$ (meaning around $p$, $X$ corresponds to points where $t=0$).

Now, given your normal vector field $V$, orient $X\cap U_p$ by declaring the ordered basis $\{\partial_{x_i}\}$ to be positively oriented iff the ordered basis $\{\partial_{x_i}, v\}$ is positively oriented in $Y$.

Conversely, if $X$ is oriented, define $V = \partial_t$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that all this works.

Comment: I see... but don't you need to pick the slice chart so that its differential (on TY) preserves orientation? How can we do that?

Comment: On each chart, you pick an individual orientation.  If you can pick them so that on overlaps they agree, you've oriented $X$.  I'm telling you how to pick them on slice charts - you still have to verify that on overlaps, the choice agrees.

Comment: I was asking about the converse.

Comment: Oh, I see!  You start with slice charts whose differential (on $TX$) preserves orientation.  Then the question is, do you pick $V = \partial_t$ or $V = -\partial_t$?  Pick it in such a way that $\{\partial_{x_i}, \pm\partial_t\}$ is positively oriented (in $TY$).  (I definitely could have given a better hint for that part.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito How do we then know that V is smooth?

Comment: @gofvonx:  $V$ is a coordinate vector field and coordinate vector fields are always smooth:  If $f$ is smooth then, $\partial_i f = \frac{d}{dx^1} f\circ x^{-1}$ is the derivative of a compositioin of smooth functions.  (You pick $V = \partial_t$ or $V = -\partial_t$ once for the whole chart: Using an argument relying on the disconnectedness of $GL_n$, one shows the choice at one point uniquely determines the choice at every point.)

Comment: O guess you could also prove that X is orientable by doing the contraction of the volume form of Y by the normal vector field?

Comment: @SeñorBilly:  Yes, that should work.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question. Why $\partial_t$ is normal?

Comment: @Ning:  Strictly speaking, the manifolds in question aren't Riemannian so there isn't a true notion of "normal" in the sense of "perpendicular to the surface".  Rather, it's normal in the sense that it's non-zero in the vector bundle $TY|_X/TX$.    As to why it's normal in this sense, this has to do with how slice coordinates work.  The coordinates $(x_1,...,x_n,t)$ are coordinates for an open subset in $Y$ with the special property that $(x_1,....,x_n,0)$ form coordinates on an relatively open subset of $X$.  Then, by definition of coordinates, $\partial_t$ is not in the span of all the...

Comment: $\partial_{x_i}$, so $\partial_t$ is *not* in $TX$, so it's non-zero in $TY|_X/TX$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative proof using some facts about the first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1$.

We have a short exact sequence of vector bundles on $X$:

$$0 \to TX \to i^*TY \to \nu \to 0$$

where $i : X \to Y$ is the inclusion, and $\nu$ denotes the normal bundle of $X$ in $Y$. Therefore $w_1(i^*TY) = w_1(TX) + w_1(\nu)$. As $Y$ is orientable, $w_1(TY) = 0$ so $w_1(i^*TY) = i^*w_1(TY) = 0$ and hence $w_1(TX) = w_1(\nu)$. So $X$ is orientable if and only if $w_1(\nu) = 0$, but as $\nu$ is a line bundle ($X$ has codimension one), this is equivalent to $\nu$ being trivial. Therefore $X$ is orientable if and only if $\nu$ has a nowhere-zero section (i.e. $X$ admits a nowhere-zero normal vector field).