# Question about the (pseudo)-holomorphic map between almost complex manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, almost-complex

It may be a very simple question,but I can't figure it out.

> Let $(M,I)$ be an almost complex manifold where $I$ is an almost complex structure.Then $-I$ is also an almost complex structure.Then the identity map $id:(M,I)\rightarrow (M,-I)$ is (pseduo)-holomorphic.

Here,[image]

Here is what I think:if $z_i\in T^{1,0}(M)$,then $I(z_i)=iz_i$,$-I(z_i)=-i(z_i)$,however,$id_*=id$,I can't get $id_*\circ I=(-I)\circ id_*$.I wanna know where I did wrong.Can anyone give me some advice?

By the way,any notes including the **explicit examples** about (pseduo)-holomorphic map are appreciated.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not use $i$ as both a complex number and an index. This is very confusing in complex geometry. ... You should be computing on tangent vectors, not on coordinates, but, nevertheless what is true is that the image of the tangent space is a complex subspace under the new almost-complex structure, but the equation sure seems to fail vector by vector. (Compute $I(\partial/\partial x_j) = \partial/\partial y_j$ and $I(\partial/\partial y_j) = -\partial/\partial x_j$, etc.)

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin,thanks for your comment.So do you mean the claim is not right?In fact,I came across this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367602/two-almost-complex-structure-define-isomorphic-complex-manifolds    ,so I ask this question.Can you give me some advice for my another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367602/two-almost-complex-structure-define-isomorphic-complex-manifolds   ?Thanks a lot.

Comment: The identity is definitely *not* $(I,-I)$-holomorphic. Changing $I$ by $-I$ essentially says that all holomorphic objects according to the first structure become anti-holomorphic with respect to the second structure, but the two concepts are not the same.

Comment: Dear @IvoTerek,thank you!

Comment: @Steve: I commented on your other question.

Comment: @TedShifrin,thank you so much!I still have some confusion in my other question, can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

The claim is wrong. Take for example the complex manifold $\mathbb C$ which is an alomost complex manifold as well. $\operatorname{id}:(\mathbb C,i)\to (\mathbb C,-i)$ being (pseduo)-holomorphic is equivalent to $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, $z \mapsto \overline z$ being holomorphic which is of course not the case.